# Segmentation Fault using Python Shared Memory

Tags: python, macos, numpy, shared-memory, python-3.8

The function `store_in_shm` writes a numpy array to the shared memory while the second function `read_from_shm` creates a numpy array using data in the same shared memory space and returns the numpy array.

However, running the code in Python 3.8 gives the following segmentation error:

> zsh: segmentation fault  python foo.py

Why is there no problem accessing the numpy array from inside the function `read_from_shm`, but a segmentation error appears when accessing the numpy array again outside of the function?

**Output:**

```
From read_from_shm(): [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
zsh: segmentation fault  python foo.py
% /Users/athena/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:203: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

**foo.py**

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def store_in_shm(data):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='foo', create=True, size=data.nbytes)
    shmData = np.ndarray(data.shape, dtype=data.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    shmData[:] = data[:]
    shm.close()
    return shm

def read_from_shm(shape, dtype):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='foo', create=False)
    shmData = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    print('From read_from_shm():', shmData)
    return shmData

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.arange(10)
    shm = store_in_shm(data)
    shmData = read_from_shm(data.shape, data.dtype)
    print('From __main__:', shmData)    # no seg fault if we comment this line
    shm.unlink()
```

Comment: I've typically run into problems with python's multiprocessing managers, and just use `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` and a `multiprocessing.Lock` for manual synchronization. With your example I actually get different answers with Mac vs Windows where windows can't seem to re-open the file after being `close()`d within the same process. The error you get suggests that it wants you to also `close` shm from within `read_from_shm` because it's saying you're not `close()`ing something.

Comment: Apparently with Windows `unlink` actually does nothing, and the file is destroyed once all currently open copies are closed, so the memory is destroyed in-between `store_in_shm` and `read_from_shm` resulting in the file not found error.

Comment: @Aaron if we do `shm.close()` inside `read_from_shm`, I think the numpy array `shmData` have problem accessing its buffer in `shm` as `shm` is now closed.

Comment: yah, I'm still looking to figure out how it's supposed to work. I'll post an actual answer if I figure it out for real...

Comment: I may have to eventually retract my statement on preferring `sharedctypes`. After diving the code, it seems like `shared_memory` may be a bit simpler and more lightweight (although they do work in a similar manner under the hood). There are just apparently a few bugs to still work out...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the problem seems to be that the underlying mmap'ed file (owned by `shm` within `read_from_shm`) is being closed when `shm` is garbage collected when the function returns. Then `shmData` refers back to it, which is where you get the segfault (for referring to a closed mmap) This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9537), but it can be solved by keeping a reference to `shm`.

Additionally all `SharedMemory` instances want to be `close()`'d with exactly one of them being `unlink()`'ed when it is no longer necessary. If you don't call `shm.close()` yourself, it will be called at GC as mentioned, and on Windows if it is the only one currently "open" the shared memory file will be deleted. When you call `shm.close()` inside `store_in_shm`, you introduce an OS dependency as on windows the data will be deleted, and MacOS and Linux, it will retain until `unlink` is called.

Finally though this doesn't appear in your code, [another problem](https://bugs.python.org/issue38119) currently exists where accessing data from independent processes (rather than child processes) can similarly delete the underlying mmap too soon. `SharedMemory` is a very new library, and hopefully all the kinks will work out soon.

You can re-write the given example to retain a reference to the "second" `shm` and just use either one to `unlink`:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def store_in_shm(data):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='foo', create=True, size=data.nbytes)
    shmData = np.ndarray(data.shape, dtype=data.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    shmData[:] = data[:]
    #there must always be at least one `SharedMemory` object open for it to not
    #  be destroyed on Windows, so we won't `shm.close()` inside the function,
    #  but rather after we're done with everything.
    return shm

def read_from_shm(shape, dtype):
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='foo', create=False)
    shmData = np.ndarray(shape, dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    print('From read_from_shm():', shmData)
    return shm, shmData #we need to keep a reference of shm both so we don't
                        #  segfault on shmData and so we can `close()` it.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.arange(10)
    shm1 = store_in_shm(data)
    #This is where the *Windows* previously reclaimed the memory resulting in a 
    #  FileNotFoundError because the tempory mmap'ed file had been released.
    shm2, shmData = read_from_shm(data.shape, data.dtype)
    print('From __main__:', shmData)
    shm1.close() 
    shm2.close()
    #on windows "unlink" happens automatically here whether you call `unlink()` or not.
    shm2.unlink() #either shm1 or shm2
```

Comment: Logically, you must still have a reference to the SharedMemory object to close it, and you wouldn't probably assume you can still access the data it's backing (the numpy array) after closing. It seems like [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9537) may be the underlying reason the dereference is missed, and segfault is thrown.

Comment: "keeping a reference to shm"

Is there a way to store a reference somewhere to workaround this bug automatically? I want to create a large number of shared_memory backed numpy arrays. I guess I could keep a huge list of pointers and append a reference to it whenever I make a new array? Is there a more Pythonic way of doing that?

Comment: @ike maybe create a subclass of ndarray which handles creating the array from the buffer then hangs on to the reference for you? Probably should then define `__del__` too to call `unlink` so the file gets deleted when it's not needed anymore on *nix systems

Comment: The problem is, I'm creating different ndarrays backed by the same buffer in different threads. I need to store these references somewhere, but I run into the same sharing issue all over again - if I only keep them in the thread that allocated them I seem to be getting segfaults.

Comment: @ike obligatory: "be very careful mixing threads and processes: `fork` does not play nice at all with multithreading" This is basically the same issue as OP had... you must always have a reference somewhere or the temporary file backing it will get deleted by the os (delete file when all handles are closed). Honestly in this case I'd just make a list at the module level in the parent process, and stuff all shm objects into it, then do something like get the length of the list (anything really that refers to it) at the end of the process so it doesn't ever get garbage collected.

Comment: I meant processes, not threads. 

Will try the len list trick, although I think I'm getting segfaults before it "should have" been GCed.

Comment: basically the file has to be open by at least one process **always** or it will be immediately deleted. If they're all created in the parent process, and there's a reference to them that will outlive all child processes, there should be no problem. Creating them in the children is much harder. You can do all the work in a child, but instantiate in the parent. kinda sounding like this might be worth it's own question imo...

Comment: the problem is I'm creating them on-demand in the children and then expect it to be available to all children. I guess I can set aside one process to create them.

Comment: "before it should have been GC'd" things are gc'd immediately when they go out of scope. incremental GC is only for cleaning up circular references

Comment: I stored it in a variable of a class, and I confirmed it isn't GCed, but it's still crashing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227978/discussion-between-ike-and-aaron).

Comment: great! solved my problem

Comment: If you are here, I suggest to you looking at Ray's remote decorator rather than shoehorning the standard library's pool and shared memory aparatuses.