# FileNotFoundError when passing a shared memory to a new process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing application, where I want to pass `numpy` array data back and forth.
The idea is to use a `SharedMemoryManager.SharedMemory()` and have `numpy` arrays pointing to the same buffer of this shared memory. Using locks should avoid race conditions.

Here is the important part of the code:

**creating the process**

```
buffer = self.data_manager.SharedMemory(size=(w * h * c))
queue = self.data_manager.Queue()
lock = self.data_manager.Lock()
stop_event = self.data_manager.Event()

frame_buffer = np.ndarray(
    (h, w, c),
    dtype=np.uint8,
    buffer=buffer.buf,
)

proc = Process(
    target=run_camera,
    name=camera_request.name,
    kwargs={
        "command_queue": queue,
        "lock": lock,
        "stop_event": stop_event,
        "shared_buffer": buffer,
        # other parameters
    },
)


proc.start()
```

**target function**

```
def run_camera(
    command_queue: Queue[CameraCommand],
    lock: Lock,
    stop_event: Event,
    shared_buffer: shared_memory.SharedMemory,
    # other parameters

) -> None:

    frame_buffer = np.ndarray(
        (h, w, c),
        dtype=np.uint8,
        buffer=shared_buffer.buf,
    )
    # do stuff with the array
```

The problem is, that as soon as the new process is started I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\path\to\Miniconda3\envs\trumpf\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
> exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
> File "C:\path\to\Miniconda3\envs\trumpf\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
> self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
> File "C:\path\to\Miniconda3\envs\trumpf\lib\multiprocessing\shared_memory.py", line 161, in **init**
> h_map = _winapi.OpenFileMapping( FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'wnsm_3ab8096f'

After searching for quite a while, I still can't figure out what the reason for this issue is. Even weirder is, that if I place a breakpoint at the line `proc.start()` and simply let the program continue after hitting it, the error does not appear. This initially had me thinking it was some timing issue, however testing around with `time.sleep()` didn't change anything so far.

Comment: What is `type(self.data_manager)`?

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal it is defined as `class DataManager(SharedMemoryManager, SyncManager):`. However, I think I have just found the issue, that causes the problem. I will post an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I was able to sort out the problem:

It seems (I'm wondering if anyone can confirm this) like the following was happening - at least this is what I can gather from debugging.

The code *creating the process* above was executed within a class method. Since the shared memory `buffer` was destroyed at the end of the method `buffer.close()` was called automatically.
With `proc.start()` being the last line of the method, this seemed to be happening while the new process was started.
From my understanding passing a `SharedMemory` to a new process, will cause a new instantiation with the same name as the passed instance. Since, in my case `closed()` was called before, this name wouldn't exist anymore, causing the Exception.

The simple solution to the problem was to keep `buffer` around as a class member. Now the crash doesn't happen anymore.

As mentioned, I'm curious if anyone can confirm if my understanding of the issue is correct. If so, should this even be possible?

Comment: [(old answer of mine)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63717188/3220135)  This is expected behavior on windows that the file (memory mapped file which backs the shared memory) is immediately removed if there are no currently open handles. No explicit call to `unlink` is needed (`shm.unlink` is actually a noop on windows). If you create the `shm` in a function scope and don't keep a reference, it will be garbage collected when the function returns and the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Windows implementation of python
- with linux, you do not need to keep the buffer reference around
- the behavior does not match the documentation at docs.python.org