# Functions to initialize and load a SharedMemory array

Tags: python

How do I write functions to be imported in other parts of the code so I can initialize and/or load a shared array? I don't need it to be super fancy atm so I'm trying this simple approach:

```
# functions.py

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


def init_shared_array(shape, dtype, name):
    zeros = np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=zeros.nbytes, name=name)
    shared_array = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    shared_array[:] = zeros[:]
    return name

def load_shared_array(shape, dtype, name):
    shm = SharedMemory(create=False, name=name)
    shared_array = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    return shared_array
```

```
# main.py

from functions import init_shared_array, load_shared_array

shape = (1,)
dtype = int
name = 'MySharedArray'

init_shared_array(shape, dtype, name)

shared_array = load_shared_array(shape, dtype, name)  # I'll run this line on other files to
```

I wasn't expecting it to fail, but it does when loading the array, with a warning `UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects to clean up` followed by an error `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

One curious thing I noticed is that if instead of calling the `load_shared_array` method I just replace it with its code, then the program works:

```
# main.py

import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from functions import init_shared_array, load_shared_array

shape = (1,)
dtype = int
name = 'MySharedArray'

init_shared_array(shape, dtype, name)

shm = SharedMemory(create=False, name=name)
shared_array = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)  # works well
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer on [Segmentation Fault using Python Shared Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713241/segmentation-fault-using-python-shared-memory). Turns out I needed to keep a reference of `shm` and return it together with `shared_array` inside `load_shared_array`:

```
def load_shared_array(shape, dtype, name):
    shm = SharedMemory(create=False, name=name)
    shared_array = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    return shared_array, shm
```